# How to download image from node server sending image filename in HTTP post request from Angular 2

Tags: node.js, angular2-services

I want to download an image from node server when sending post request for image file name.But I couldn't get either save dialog box or direct download.I have a folder uploads from which I want to read the image and download.I am trying the code pasted over here.Please help me with a good solution.

```
    router.post('/download', urlencodedParser, function(req, res) {
    var img = path.resolve('uploads/' + req.body.file);
    var filename = path.basename(img);
    var mimetype = mime.lookup(img);

    console.log(filename);
    console.log(mimetype);

    res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + filename);
    res.setHeader('Content-type', mimetype);

    var filestream = fs.createReadStream(img);
    filestream.pipe(res);

    res.on('finish', function(){
        console.log("Download complete");
    });
})
```

Comment: What values do you get for filename and mimetype? Does the final log print?

Comment: Yes I have the final log print
image/jpeg for mimetype. When I send request the function  
private setHeaders(): Headers {
    const headersConfig = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    };
return new Headers(headersConfig);
  }
get called to set headers

Comment: Please respond to my first question as well. Also, can you inspect from the client side, what response headers you get? Are the headers you set reflecting properly? Also is content-length header set?

Comment: I couldn't inspect from the client side what response headers I got.Basically I need save dialog box and response with an object